# finding the width of a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

Finding the width of binary tree.

In my code for each leave i create a entry in a hash map and keep updating it when i found a node at leave i.Finally i will iterate the hashmap to find max width.But how can i do it without using any classleel/global varaiables?

```
Map<Integer,Integer> mp = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
void width(Node node,int level){
        if(node==null)
            return;
        if(mp.containsKey(level)){
            int count = mp.get(level);
            mp.put(level, count+1);
        }else{
            mp.put(level, 1);
        }

        width(node.left, level+1);
        width(node.right, level+1);

    }
```

Comment: You can  make your variable as "width" return type. And why do you use  Map<Integer,Integer> instead of int?

Comment: On a perfectly balanced tree the width would be 2^(n-1) where n is the height of the tree.  If you have one node the height is one and you have 2^0 which is 1.  If you had 3 nodes (height of 2), then its 2^1 which is 2, etc

Comment: Yes, however the question does not state that it is perfectly balanced.

Comment: Note that the number of nodes per level is not a good indication of how "wide" the tree is. An extremely unbalanced binary tree can have no more than two nodes per level yet be extremely wide, if nodes on the left side have only left children and nodes on the right side have only right children.

Comment: An aside, you might like what `Collections.max(mp.values())` gives you if you're not already using it.  Also, the map is a bit redundant over a simple indexed list such as `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: The other problem is that the question does not say how the width of a tree is "measured".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create the HashMap inside the method, then move all the work into an auxillary method, like this:

```
void width(Node node,int level){
    Map<Integer,Integer> mp = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    widthImpl(mp, node, level);
    // find maximum
}

private void widthImpl(Map<Integer,Integer> mp, Node node, int level) {
    if(node==null)
        return;
    if(mp.containsKey(level)){
        int count = mp.get(level);
        mp.put(level, count+1);
    }else{
        mp.put(level, 1);
    }

    widthImpl(mp, node.left, level+1);
    widthImpl(mp, node.right, level+1);
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer to the question that was asked.  All of the other answers try to change the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to keep track of the number of nodes per level.

Define the horizontal position of each node as the number of right children minus the number of left children that were traversed from the root to the node. The width will then be the maximum horizontal position minus the minimum horizontal position. The min/max positions could be passed around a recursive traversal in an array of two components.

Here's a code example of what I mean:

```
int getWidth(Node node) {
    // current[0] is the number of left children traversed of the current path
    // current[1] is the number of right children traversed of the current path
    int[] current = { 0, 0 };
    // extremes[0] is the minimum horizontal position
    // extremes[1] is the maximum horizontal position
    int[] extremes = { 0, 0 };
    computeExtremes(node, current, extremes);
    return (extremes[1] - extremes[0]);
}

void computeExtremes(Node node, int[] current, int[] extremes) {
    if (node == null) { return; }
    int position = current[1] - current[0];
    if (extremes[0] > position) {
        extremes[0] = position;
    }
    if (extremes[1] < position) {
        extremes[1] = position;
    }
    current[0]++;
    computeExtremes(node.left, current, extremes);
    current[0]--;
    current[1]++;
    computeExtremes(node.right, current, extremes);
    current[1]--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you want to do something like this?

```
public Map<Integer,Integer> width( Node node ) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> mp = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    width( node, 1, mp );
    return mp;
}

private void width( Node node, int level, Map<Integer,Integer> mp ) {
    if(node==null)
        return;
    if(mp.containsKey(level)){
        int count = mp.get(level);
        mp.put(level, count+1);
    }else{
        mp.put(level, 1);
    }

    width(node.left, level+1);
    width(node.right, level+1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses @nathan's algo, but passes by value.

```
Pair<int, int> extremes(Node node, int x, int y) {
  if (node == null) return makePair(x,y);
  Pair p1 = extremes(node.left, x-1, y);
  Pair p2 = extremes(node.right, x, y+1);
  return makePair(min(p1.x, p2.x), max(p1.y, p2.y))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-width-of-a-binary-tree/

**Use recursive with hash table**

```
int getWidth(struct node* root, int level)
{

  if(root == NULL)
    return 0;

  if(level == 1)
    return 1;

  else if (level > 1)
    return getWidth(root->left, level-1) + 
             getWidth(root->right, level-1);
}
```

**Use queue to dequeue parent and replace with children nodes**

```
static int maxwidth(node root) 
    {
        // Base case
        if (root == null)
            return 0;

        // Initialize result
        int maxwidth = 0;

        // Do Level order traversal keeping 
        // track of number of nodes at every level
        Queue<node> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(root);
        while (!q.isEmpty()) 
        {
            // Get the size of queue when the level order
            // traversal for one level finishes
            int count = q.size();

            // Update the maximum node count value
            maxwidth = Math.max(maxwidth, count);

            // Iterate for all the nodes in 
            // the queue currently
            while (count-- > 0) 
            {
                // Dequeue an node from queue
                node temp = q.remove();

                // Enqueue left and right children 
                // of dequeued node
                if (temp.left != null) 
                {
                    q.add(temp.left);
                }
                if (temp.right != null) 
                {
                    q.add(temp.right);
                }
            }
        }
        return maxwidth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something a little different:

```
int[] width(Node node){
    if(node==null) {
        return new int[]{};
    }
    int[] la = width(node.left);
    int[] ra = width(node.right);
    return merge(1, la, ra);
}


private int[] merge(int n0, int[] la, int[] ra) {
    int maxLen = Math.max(la.length, ra.length);
    int[] result = new int[maxLen+1];
    result[0] = n0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLen; ++i) {
        result[i+1] = i >= la.length
                ? ra[i] : i >= ra.length
                ? la[i] : la[i] + ra[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```